# Accept Github Copilot inline suggestion with right arrow key instead of tab in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

As mentioned, how can I accept the Github Copilot inline suggestion with the right arrow key instead of the `tab` key in VSCode?

Comment: Funny, I came here looking how to *prevent* right arrow from accepting suggestions (it turned out I was pressing Ctrl+Right Arrow as I often do, according to the keyboard assignment to `editor.action.inlineSuggest.acceptNextWord`, thanks @GregoryL for the hint!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Click `File -> Preferences -> Keyboard` shortcuts.
2. Search for `'editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit'` (command that accepts the Copilot suggestion).
3. Double click it and assign new shortcut, for example `right arrow key`.

Comment: It works most of the time, but sometimes it just move the cursor instead of accepting the suggestion.
For example when the autocomplete modal is open.
I tried to modify the "when" condition of several shortcuts but without any success. Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: For some reason both tab and right arrow key will accept copilot then