# Is there no way to change the copilot inline suggestion trigger hotkey in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, github-copilot

I have found [solutions for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73705091/accept-github-copilot-inline-suggestion-with-right-arrow-key-instead-of-tab-in-v), but nothing for Visual Studio. When I search for copilot options I dont see any options like described. I am basically trying to use the ` key instead of tab on Windows.

Is there any other ways around this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/configuring-github-copilot/configuring-github-copilot-in-your-environment?tool=visualstudio#keyboard-shortcuts-for-github-copilot-1) suggests this option is not available in Visual Studio

Comment: I think you're right, sad. Tab is such an annoying key to use

Answer (score 0):

In the settings for intellicode you can check this box and this will allow you to use the right arrow to accept the code.  This will apply this behavior to both Intellisence and copilot's suggestions

[image]